# How to create a sequence field on Grails without being a primary key and related to another field?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Domain where I need to create an Integer as a sequence starting with 1. And it should start at one for every new site I have.
So let's say I have this class named Invoice

```
Invoice{
   Site site
   Integer invoiceNumber
   //Other attributes
}
```

So what I want to do is:
the invoiceNumber will start at 1, for every different Site I have.

```
Site{
   String siteName;
}
```

Assuming I have 3 different sites with siteNames: "Site 1", "Site 2" and "Site 3"

If I have 5 invoices for "Site 1", the invoiceNumbers should be: 1,2,3,4,5.
If I have 3 invoices for "Site 2", the invoiceNumbers should be: 1,2,3
And so on...

How can I create this structure with Grails to represent this sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check this code, but the idea is simple:

```
class Invoice {
   Site site
   Integer invoiceNumber

   def beforeInsert() {
      if (!invoiceNumber) { // just in case you will pass this number by yourself for some reason
         def lastInvoice = Invoice.countBySite(site)
         invoiceNumber = lastInvoice + 1
      }
   }
}
```